# Lazarus cross platform equivalent to MapVirtualKey

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I have been able to successfully retrieve ascii characters from VK codes
using lazarus/fpc and the mapvirtualkey function in windows.

Is there a cross platform (macOS specifically) lazarus/fpc equivalent to mapvirtualkey? Is there any other way to get the ascii/unicode character that corresponds to a VK code under the current keyboard layout using lazarus/fpc on macOS?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: (Rephrased question) The onKeyDown events on Lazarus on a Mac provide a "Key" parameter. Is there a way on the mac to convert this parameter to the ascii/unicode character that corresponds to this "Key"?

Comment: What is the Mac equivalent of virtual key codes?

Comment: It is the "Key" parameter passed to onKeyDown events.

Comment: Yes, but what is actually in that value. Virtual key code is a Windows specific concept. What is the same concept on Mac?

Comment: It seams to work the same way. It is related to the hardware button and it is independent to the keyboard layout/language settings. For the "p" key for example, the VK code is 80 (same as windows) regardless if you have an english keyboard (in this case, it corresponds to letter "p" when pressed without shift) or, for example, a greek keyboard (which corresponds to letter "π" without shift).

Comment: Guess work won't get you far. Try to find out what the underlying system asking. Asking for a like for like function replacement is unrealistic.

Comment: David, let me rephrase the question: The onKeyDown events on Lazarus on a Mac provide a "Key" parameter. Is there a way on the mac to convert this parameter to the ascii code that corresponds to this "Key"?

Comment: That would be a better question. You should ask that. With an edit. Why Ascii though ? You don't want to to support internationalisation?

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I have edited the question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm kind of confused about what you want also. 
But maybe this helps:

Look in the lcltype unit in the lazarus folders, this contains all the "virtual Key" constants (search for vk_ ).

So the "Key" parameter is getting the double value corresponding to VK_RETURN when the Return/Enter key is pressed. And so on with all the extended keyboard characters.

You can use the Ord() and Chr() functions with these values as well which, I believe, will give you want you want (?).

If you are going to use these codes don't forget to add lcltype to your "uses" section.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I'm looking for. 
In other words, I would like to know which character will be produced on the user's keyboard when 
the user presses e.g. the third button from the left on the top 
row, together with shift.  In a US keyboard this will produce a @
character. On an english keyboard it will produce some other 
character.  On windows this is done via the MapVirtualKey function. 
But, I cannot find how to do it on a mac...